# Proof verification: If f is injective, f has a left inverse

Tags: functions, inverse

I would appreciate verification of the following proof attempt, please.  I suspect it is faulty at step 3, as I don't know whether I can use the existence of *g* as defined below as a premise.

Statement: If a map *f* is injective, *f* has a left inverse.

Proof:

1. Let $f : A \rightarrow B$ be injective.
2. Then, if $a_{1} \neq a_{2}$, $f(a_{1}) \neq f(a_{2})$. It follows that if $f(a_{1}) = f(a_{2})$, then $a_{1} = a_{2}$.
3. Let the map *g* be defined as $g : B \rightarrow A$; $g(f(a)) = a$, $\forall a \in A$.
4. As $f(a_{1}) = f(a_{2})$, $g(f(a_{1})) = g(f(a_{2})) = a_{1} = a_{2}$, and therefore $g \circ f : A \rightarrow A$ is an identity map on A.  As such, *f* has a left inverse.

Thanks all.

Comment: Are you sure $g$, as given, is a function from $B$ to $A$? In particular, is $g$ defined for every $b \in B$?

Comment: I think there's a (minor) missing assumption in the statement: if $B$ is nonempty, then the empty function $\emptyset \to B$ is injective, but there are no functions $g : B \to \emptyset$ at all, much less any left inverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Indeed, you need to define $g$ in order to show that a left inverse exists.
What lacks in your definition of $g$ is how an element of $B \diagdown f(A)$ is mapped to $A$. Of course, $B \diagdown f(A)$ could be the empty set, but for the general case, we don't know.

Since $A \neq \emptyset$, let $k \in A$. Since $f$ is injective, it follows that $h: f(A) \to A, b \mapsto f^{-1}(b)$ is bijective. Then we define $g(y)=\begin{cases} k &  y \in B\diagdown f(A) \\ h(y) & y \in f(A)\end{cases}$

Now we get for all $a\in A$ that $g(f(a))=a$, so $g \circ f = id_{A}$.

Comment: If I'm understanding correctly, the main issue is that *g* as I defined it has a domain that potentially stretches beyond that of *f(A)*, so I need to make sure that the definition of *g* covers all of B as the domain?  I'm fuzzy on where bijectivity comes into it.

Comment: Exactly. Well, a map is bijective if it is surjective and injective. If it is injective and just goes from its domain to its image (note that here we take the codomain to be the image), then for every element in the image we can find one element which is mapped to it (by definition of the image), that means that it is surjective. Alltogether the map is bijective.

Comment: And the bijectivity of h is necessary to establish that h maps back onto all of A in a one-to-one manner, right?

Comment: Yes, exactly like you say

Answer (score 3):

Your $g$ is defined on $Im f$. If you want $g$ defined on $B$, you can set $g(b)=a_0$ for $b\in B\backslash Im f$, where $a_0\in A$ is fixed. (if $A=\emptyset$, the result is trivial).